# convert C# code to android - Date Conversion Consultation

Tags: c#, android

i try to convert C# code to android, **for this date = 01/04/2020**

C#

```
This = Convert.ToDateTime(dtDate.Value.ToShortDateString() + " 00:00:00");
Past = Convert.ToDateTime("01/01/1988 00:00:00");
difference = This - Past;
MINUTE = (int)difference.TotalMinutes;
ToPRI.Text = MINUTE.ToString();
```

**The right result is: 16961760**

android

```
public static String Pri_Date2(String date)
{
    date = date + " 00:00:00";
    DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss");
    try {
           This = df.parse(date);
           Past =  df.parse("01/01/1988 00:00:00");
           diff =  This.getTime() - Past.getTime();
        }
   catch (Exception r) {
   }
        long diffInMinutes = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(diff);
        return String.valueOf(diffInMinutes);
}
```

**The wrong result:  16961700**

Can anyone tell me what the problem is and why the results are not the same?

Comment: What is the timezone? It looks like the android computation considers `01/04/2020 00:00:00` to be in daylight savings time, while `01/01/1988 00:00:00` is in standard time

Comment: I think it's not an issue of TimeZone, since the difference is only 60 between the two values, it could be an issue of milliseconds

Comment: Joni, You're right. but How do I make both dates work on that time